# Show different views in recyclerview adapter on the comparison of two lists

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, retrofit, android-room

I am having a scenario in which I want to show two different items in one adapter.
Here is a scenario,
I have two lists on which I want to make a comparison, one list which is coming back end and one is coming from my local room database. Basically, I need to list the items coming from back-end, in these items which exist in my database will have different view in adapter and and if the item coming from backend does not exist in my database will have different views.

If I'll make comparison in adapter it will violate MVVM as I cannot write the business logic in the adapter.

Any suggestions with the best practice in my scenario please?

Comment: So, just do the comparison in the VM layer? What's stopping you?

Comment: and then send the filtered list in adapter? is it what you're trying to say?

Comment: Yes, if you're strictly following MVVM, you prepare the list in the VM or M layer and send the fully filtered and prepared list to the View.

Comment: actually, I am passing the list to adapter which is coming from backend and this list does not have any param through which I can decide the placement of different views. The solution which I had in my mind was on the M layer to add an additional param in the model and assign the value to this param when I am comparing the list in VM layer and in adapter I can place the different views on the basis of that specific param but I am not sure if this is the good practice or not.

Comment: There's probably a hundred ways you could do it between the M and VM layers that would be fine. Following general MVVM strategy, the logic you're describing makes sense to be put in the VM layer. If you're strict about the no business logic in the View, then the only thing you need to be sure to do is to pass a List of items that contain everything the adapter could possibly need to know to display it.